# How to remove extra space end of a sentence

Tags: html, css

I have a P tag, and the end of a sentence always gives me extra space. I tried to fix it with padding, but not helpful; I want all lines to start and end the same. When I have 3 line sentence, the end of the first line will not end in the same place as title line.

[image]

```css
CSS
.notAcceptingPatients {
 padding: 11px ;
 background: rgba(219, 88, 88, 0.1);
 border-radius: 8px;

p {
margin: 2px;
font-size: 15px;
color: $black;
background: none;
line-height: 19px;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 1px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div className="notAcceptingPatients col-med-6"\>
<h6 className="font-weight-bold text-dark "\>
<i
style={{
color: '#D14444',
fontSize: 23,
marginRight: 6,
}}
class="fa fa-info-circle"\>\</i\>

This Dental Clinic is not accepting new patients at
this time \</h6\>
<p className="notAcceptingPatients ml-2"\>
<p\>
the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\</p\>
</p\>
</div\>
```

Comment: Your CSS contains typos: 'backslashes' are not used in HTML tags unless you are using a code pre-processor of some kind. Without a pre-processor they will cause errors and need to be removed first. After that, `p { text-align: justify }` seems to be the solution to your issue...

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is what you meant, because your snippet has some issues, but you might want to add `text-align: justify;` to the `<p>` tag and see if it gives the result you want